# Applying textures to only one object in opengl

Tags: opengl, object, textures, scene

I'm programming in c++ in opengl.
I'm supposed to make a texture and I made the following code:

```
void makeCheckImage(void){
int i, j, c;

for (i = 0; i < checkImageHeight; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < checkImageWidth; j++) {
        c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8))==0))*255;
        checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) 255;
    }
}
}

void init(void){   
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    makeCheckImage();
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glGenTextures(1, &texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                    GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                    GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, checkImageWidth, 
                 checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                 checkImage);
}
```

my problem is that this beautiful piece of code (or maybe not) is applying textures to the whole scene! And I just want it to apply to one object... 
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//Draw object
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: worked better, but the rest of the objects are still a little weirdly looking

Comment: `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)` would be a better practice